# Separated activity, intentservice and broadcastreveiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

Assuming we've got an activity, an intentservice and a broadcastreceiver in our project all separated in different java files. Can anybody extendedly explain a scenario that the intentservice gets GCM push messages, the broadcastreceiver informs the activity about the incoming message and the activity instantly shows the message through a text box?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want the scenario or how to do it? I just implemented it in one of my  application.

Comment: Both would be great.

Comment: In my app when app is open we give user an option to ignore the app or go to the screen defined in the push notification data. I am using this approach so that even if user clicks on the notification app don't launch a new screen without prompting the same.

Comment: What about discarding the notification approach and showin the message directly in antivity in a text box or something?

Comment: Please see my answer. I hope it helps you. It a working code which I implemented yesterday only.

Comment: Do let me know if this works for you. I would like to see that this approach can be used in other apps too.... :D

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it.

**Step 1** Create a base activity and all other activities should extend it.

**Step 2** In your custom application (say `MyApplication.class`) class add these four methods and two variables

```
private static boolean activityVisible = false;
private static Context activityOnTop = null;

public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
}

public static Context getActivityOnTop(){
    return activityOnTop;
}

public static void activityResumed(Context classContext) {
    activityVisible = true;
    activityOnTop = classContext;
}

public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
}
```

**Step 3** In the base activity (which all other are extending) do this

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.activityResumed(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPaused() {
    super.onPaused();
    MyApplication.activityPaused(this);
}
```

**Step 4** In your broadcast receiver when you get the notification event do this

```
if(!MyApplication.isActivityVisible()){
    //Show notification when app is not visible to user
    return;
}
Context currContext = MyApplication.getActivityOnTop();
if(currContext == null)
    return;
String currentActivity = currContext.getClass().getName();
if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(currentActivity)) {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Class.forName(currentActivity));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // Add the push notification message in the bundle here
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    }
}
```

**Step 5** In your base activity do this

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //get push notification message in the bundle here and show the dialog
    // DO NOT USE getIntent() here. USE THE intent THAT IS PASSED AS PARAMETER
}
```

**NOTE:**

`Strings.isNullOrEmpty()` is just a method I have created as a utility function

Comment: Wow... This is working at my end. When user gets the push notification and app is open; I am not displaying the push but a dialog instead. When app is not open we show the notification.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help. Could you please explain how separate broadcastreceiver, intentservice and activity communicate with each other through a workflow?